# change Ascii Text Font to Unicode font in Python

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, ascii

I'm want to make normal text like this:

```
Hello
```

Into This:

In python.
What should I do ?

Comment: Did you try replacing `H` with ``, etc.? What actually is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired string  is (character by character):

- (U+1D4D7, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL H (0xd835,0xdcd7)*)
- (U+1D4EE, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL E (0xd835,0xdcee)*)
- (U+1D4F5, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL L (0xd835,0xdcf5)*)
- (U+1D4F5, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL L (0xd835,0xdcf5)*)
- (U+1D4F8, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL O (0xd835,0xdcf8)*)

Apply [`str.translate` method](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) e.g. as follows:

```
import string

# mathematical bold script letters
mat_b_letters = ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(0x1D4D0, 0x1D503 + 1)])
# ascii letters
ascii_letters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase

trans_table   = ascii_letters.maketrans( ascii_letters, mat_b_letters)

print( 'Hello, StackOverflow user 19594133/God'.translate(trans_table))
```

**Result**: `.\SO\73426687.py`

> ```
> ,   19594133/
> ```

**Edit**: You could choose another Latin letters script (         
  ) using their Unicode numeric values derived from the following table when computing the `mat_b_letters` variable - having in mind that some Unicode script does not cover all Latin letters (currently, there are *holes* in [Unicode database version 14](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt), for instance `U+1D506` <strike>*MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL C*</strike> or `U+1D51D` <strike>*MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL Z*</strike>):

- (U+1D400, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdc00)*)
- (U+1D419, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdc19)*)
- (U+1D41A, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL A (0xd835,0xdc1a)*)
- (U+1D433, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdc33)*)
- (U+1D434, *MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdc34)*)
- (U+1D44D, *MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdc4d)*)
- (U+1D44E, *MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL A (0xd835,0xdc4e)*)
- (U+1D467, *MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdc67)*)
- (U+1D468, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdc68)*)
- (U+1D481, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdc81)*)
- (U+1D482, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL A (0xd835,0xdc82)*)
- (U+1D49B, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdc9b)*)
- (U+1D49C, *MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdc9c)*)
- (U+1D4B5, *MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdcb5)*)
- (U+1D4B6, *MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL A (0xd835,0xdcb6)*)
- (U+1D4CF, *MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdccf)*)
- (U+1D4D0, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdcd0)*)
- (U+1D4E9, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdce9)*)
- (U+1D4EA, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL A (0xd835,0xdcea)*)
- (U+1D503, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdd03)*)
- (U+1D504, *MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdd04)*)
- (U+1D51E, *MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR SMALL A (0xd835,0xdd1e)*)
- (U+1D537, *MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdd37)*)
- (U+1D538, *MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdd38)*)
- (U+1D552, *MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK SMALL A (0xd835,0xdd52)*)
- (U+1D56B, *MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdd6b)*)
- (U+1D56C, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdd6c)*)
- (U+1D585, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdd85)*)
- (U+1D586, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL A (0xd835,0xdd86)*)
- (U+1D59F, *MATHEMATICAL BOLD FRAKTUR SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdd9f)*)
- (U+1D5A0, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xdda0)*)
- (U+1D5B9, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xddb9)*)
- (U+1D5BA, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF SMALL A (0xd835,0xddba)*)
- (U+1D5D3, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF SMALL Z (0xd835,0xddd3)*)
- (U+1D5D4, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xddd4)*)
- (U+1D5ED, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xdded)*)
- (U+1D5EE, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD SMALL A (0xd835,0xddee)*)
- (U+1D607, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD SMALL Z (0xd835,0xde07)*)
- (U+1D608, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF ITALIC CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xde08)*)
- (U+1D621, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF ITALIC CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xde21)*)
- (U+1D622, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF ITALIC SMALL A (0xd835,0xde22)*)
- (U+1D63B, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF ITALIC SMALL Z (0xd835,0xde3b)*)
- (U+1D63C, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xde3c)*)
- (U+1D655, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xde55)*)
- (U+1D656, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC SMALL A (0xd835,0xde56)*)
- (U+1D66F, *MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC SMALL Z (0xd835,0xde6f)*)
- (U+1D670, *MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE CAPITAL A (0xd835,0xde70)*)
- (U+1D689, *MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE CAPITAL Z (0xd835,0xde89)*)
- (U+1D68A, *MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE SMALL A (0xd835,0xde8a)*)
- (U+1D6A3, *MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE SMALL Z (0xd835,0xdea3)*)

Comment: if i want to use others don't i would i do ? @JosefZ

Comment: @God  my English isn't good enough to understand you, sorry…

Comment: * if i want to use other fonts what should i do ? @JosefZ *

Comment: @God None of these are "fonts". You can only use what is built into Unicode. To find out what is possible, [you should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) look for a [Unicode chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/) and study it to find what you want, or [use a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unicode+fancy+letters) to try to find more information - this is not a question for Stack Overflow.